# Selector in selector Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

**Html:**

```
<div id='first'>
  <div id='second'></div>
</div>
```

**Jquery selector:**

```
$('#first', $('#second'));
```

---

***output:*** `[]`

I want to know if this type of **reversed** selector is valid.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context

Comment: In this case, dont make sens... you should access ID just with one selector, there cant be 2 same ID's..

Comment: It can be used like this to ask if one ID is inside another ID.

Comment: Btw, the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) explains quite well what it means. Do you need any further explanation? (You have read the documentation, haven't you?!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the context selector. It is searching for `#first` inside `$('#second')`.

It is equal to:

```
$('#second').find('#first');
```

It doesn't find anything with your HTML because you have `#second` as a child of `#first`. if you were to switch them around, it would select the `#first` element.

Comment: At least you'll know for next time :)

Comment: I wouldn't hire someone who doesn't know how to find answers in documentation, either.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$('#first #second'));
```

Comment: How will that help him understand how the original code works?

Comment: The hierarchy of the divs that he is using in the posted question clearly shows moving from one parent to the other. This example simply shows the position of the parent to its sub children and further down, the left most being the highest parent.

Comment: He didn't ask how to select the second div, that can be done with just `$("#second")`. He wanted to know the meaning of the the code he wrote.

Answer (score 0):

">" represents second is nested inside first.

This way you can separate out not just any div element,but any other element which is nested.

```
 $("div#first > div#second")
```